# Match array elements against a document value and filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents that have the following structure:
[image]

Both leagues and entries are arrays that I unwind(), but then I need to find the occurrence where the document's property "nick" is showed on "playerOrTeamName".

```
db.getCollection('summoners').aggregate([
    {"$skip": 0},
    {"$limit": 2},
    {'$unwind': '$leagues'},
    {'$unwind': '$leagues.entries'},
    {'$match': {'leagues.entries.playerOrTeamName': '$nick'}},
],{
```

allowDiskUse:true
 })

Why will the "match" portion result in 0 results? I can assure that the player's nick will always occur on entries array.

PS: limit = 2 used for simplicity sakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this fails is because `"$nick"` is meant to be the value of another field, but [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) which is basically just a "regular MongoDB query" has no concept of "using a variable" from an existing field value in order to "match" on the condition.

So instead you should be using ["aggregation logical operators"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/) which apply using either the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline stage, or instead by "filtering" the array content directly using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).

```
db.getCollection('summoners').aggregate([
    {"$skip": 0},
    {"$limit": 2},
    {'$unwind': '$leagues'},
    {'$unwind': '$leagues.entries'},
    {'$redact': {
      '$cond': {
        'if': { '$eq': [ '$leagues.entries.playerOrTeamName', '$nick' ] }
        'then': '$$KEEP',
        'else': '$$PRUNE'
      }
    }
])
```

Which performs a "logical" comparison on the field values and decides to `"$$KEEP"` where the condition is `true` or `"$$PRUNE"` from results where it was `false`.

Or directly on the array, keeping intact:

```
db.getCollection('summoners').aggregate([
    { "$skip": 0 },
    { "$limit": 2 },
    { "$addFields": {
      "leagues": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$leagues",
              "as": "l",
              "in": {
                "entries": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$l.entries",
                    "as": "e",
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$e.playerOrTeamName", "$nick" ] }
                  }
                },
                "name": "$$l.name",
                "queque": "$$l.queque",
                "tier": "$$l.tier"
              }
            }
          },
          "as": "l",
          "cond": {
            "$gt": [ { "$size": "$$l.entries" }, 0 ]
          }
        }
      }
    }}
])
```

Which essentially re-maps the arrays by applying [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to the inner `"entries"` for the comparison of fields, and where the "outer" array no longer has any results left in `"entries"` that array would be removed as well.